# Date comparison giving incorrect result

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting DateTime from API response and for some data, I am getting dummy date like below :

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00
```

Now, I want to check If I get a dummy date like above then I want to store null in my variable else the exact date.

I have a code like below but getting "NAN" :

```
console.log("2017-01-01T00:00:00" == "0001-01-01T00:00:00" ? null : moment("2017-01-01T00:00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY").year()); //output Nan
```

I am not getting whats the issue here. Can someone please help me?

Comment: How is it related to asp.net or c#?

Comment: Could it be `moment("2017-01-01T00:00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY")` ? Clearly the input is not in that format.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Actually the API is implemented in Asp.net MVC so that's why I thought may be I should mention it

Comment: NAN is not a number.  When dates are null you usually get the default which is 1/1/01 like your response.

Comment: @jdweng Yes from the server-side, I believe this is what is happening, but in the javascript why this comparison is failing? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try like this, passing the actual format to moment function, it ouputs 2017 in your case.

```
console.log("2017-01-01T00:00:00" == "0001-01-01T00:00:00" ? null : moment("2017-01-01T00:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DDT h:mm:ss").year()); //outputs 2017
```

If you want to compare dates irrespective of datetime format you can do like this:

```
console.log(moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD')); //date1
console.log(moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD')); //date2
```

And you can compare the 2 dates now, by setting what format you want, irrespective to the original format

Included also the isSame version from comments:

```
moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-10-20'); // true
```

But if you have a particular case you should consider reading the moment.js documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to compare date irrespective of datetime format? because tomorrow if someone will change the format then this will produce incorrect result right?

Comment: This is the way in which moment.js is working if you specify the format.

Comment: The only way to compare them irrespective of format is to use a temporal data type. As long as you're dealing with strings, format matters. Data interchange depends on reliable data representation. If someone changes the format, they're violating the established contract.

Comment: I updated the answer to compare not depending on format.

Comment: Or, just `moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00').isSame(moment('2017-01-01T00:00:00'))`...

Comment: @madreflection Can you post your answer with what you are suggesting please? It looks good so :)

Comment: What I suggested (or rather alluded to) is what Alexandru has in the first code block in this answer. You have to scroll off to the right to see it but it's there. Accept the answer.